# launch android emulator without android studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio, virtual-machine

I tried to create avd without android studio and I installed android sdk and set all directories in envrionement variables and i run flutter doctor and the android toolchain was installed correctly but when I run this command :

```
avdmanager create avd --name my_avd --package "system-images;android-30;google_apis;x86_64" --tag google_apis --abi x86_64 
it gives me this error :  
[=======================================] 100% Fetch remote repository...
```

Error:

```
Package path is not valid. Valid system image paths are:
null
```

I tried so much to solve the problem but I couldn't